# HTML5 Audio doesn't show Timer when run on Android Device

Tags: android, html, audio, timer, controls

I am developing a PhoneGap application that uses HTML5 Audio tag to run MP3 Audios. Although controls are on, but when the application is run on an Android phone the controls do not show up. All I can see is just the slider. In Ripple Emulator all works fine.

I am not interested in other controls but at least I should be able to display the timer.

Anyone can please suggest how can I do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether  i am right or wrong. few days back, i was struggled with integrating the audio and video tag for html5. Android browser doe'nt support the Audio/Video tag, for even i have given the controls for it, but then too it was not worked. What i done was, i used to define the script in-order to perform the mediafiles using Html5 tag.

```
String script = "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=" + "JavaScript"
            + ">function playvideo(url){window.location=url;}</SCRIPT>";
```

include the above script in you html5, and let me know whether it works or not.

Note:
I used native activity for this.

Comment: Where exactly do u want me to put this script? Between <audio></audio> tags?

Comment: Anywhere inside html file.

Comment: Didn't work. I am now exploring Media Elements instead

Answer (score 0):

I have explored and successfully replaced html5 audio with MediaElement.js

Here is my Audio tag:

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay" id="audioplayer" controls="true">
  <source src="none" type="audio/mp3">
    ****
</audio>
```

And the following script simply converts the HTML5 audio player to MediaElement player with all the controls that I wanted to see:

```
$('audio').mediaelementplayer({
        //audio { width: 250px; margin:10px;}
        defaultAudioWidth: 300,
        // default if the user doesn't specify
        defaultAudioHeight: 30,
        // width of audio player
        audioWidth: 300,
        // height of audio player
        audioHeight: 30,
        // initial volume when the player starts
        startVolume: 1.0,
        // useful for <audio> player loops
        loop: false,
        // enables Flash and Silverlight to resize to content size
        enableAutosize: true,
        // the order of controls you want on the control bar (and other plugins below)
        features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration'],
        // Hide controls when playing and mouse is not over the video
        alwaysShowControls: false,
        // force iPad's native controls
        iPadUseNativeControls: false,
        // force iPhone's native controls
        iPhoneUseNativeControls: false, 
        // force Android's native controls
        AndroidUseNativeControls: false,
        // forces the hour marker (##:00:00)
        alwaysShowHours: false,
        // show framecount in timecode (##:00:00:00)
        showTimecodeFrameCount: false,
        // used when showTimecodeFrameCount is set to true
        framesPerSecond: 25,
        // turns keyboard support on and off for this instance
        enableKeyboard: true,
        // when this player starts, it will pause other players
        pauseOtherPlayers: true,
        // array of keyboard commands
        keyActions: []

    });
```

So this is a fantastic solution if anyone is looking for a nice replacement of HTML5 Audio.